# How to pass file name to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, mp3

i want to fetch mp3 file name from ViewController and pass it to another VC named TextViewVc, currently i am using this method but i was unable to get the file name with this code

```
  @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {

       opneAudioFile(path: "Chalisa")


   }
   @IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {


    opneAudioFile(path: "well")}
```

and this was my code to get the file name

```
func opneAudioFile(path : String) {

     if let audiopath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: "mp3") {
               do {
                   let contents1 = try String(contentsOfFile: audiopath)
                   print(contents1)
                   //  Now push second ViewController form here with contents.
                      if let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TextViewVC") as? TextViewVC {
                       secondVC.content = contents1
                       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
                   }
               } catch {

                   // contents could not be loaded
               }
           } else {
               // example.txt not found!
           }


   }
```

where i am doing wrong ? or there is any another way to get the file name of mp3 ?

Comment: which code belong to which controller ? its not clear .. please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

```
String(contentsOfFile:)
```

does not return file name, but

```
let fileName = (audiopath as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

does